# Importing .bson File in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, import, mongodb-query, bson, mongo-shell

I am completely newbie to mongoDB, so i have got task to featch out data (& perform task on data using python ) from given files which are:

```
sensor_data.bson
sensor_data.metadata.json
```

I have installed mongoDb 5.0.9 community version and mongoDB Compass also,so i have tried running this command in mongo shell:

```
mongorestore -d local -c task C:/task_data/sensor_data.bson
```

but it is giving this error

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:16
```

So, my question is am i importing data correctly or i have to perform some different kind of step to import that.

Comment: try ```mongorestore --db=sensors_db --collection=task  C:/task_data/sensor_data.bson```, if still fails then either .bson is corrupted or .bson is [incompatible](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#platform-support).
(probably because of OS)